# Pixel values changing when opening and re-saving file with rasterio

Tags: rasterio

I'm using `rasterio` to analyze satellite imagery stored in JPEG2000 format and am having the problem that pixel values change when opening and then saving the same file again. Any ideas why this happens?

```py
with rasterio.open('/tmp/in.jp2') as infile:
    with rasterio.open('/tmp/out.jp2', 'w', count=infile.count, dtype=infile.dtypes[0], height=infile.height, width=infile.width, crs=infile.crs, transform=infile.transform) as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())

    with rasterio.open('/tmp/in.jp2') as f:
        data = f.read()
        print(data.min(), data.max())
        # output: 0 19614

    with rasterio.open('/tmp/out.jp2') as f:
        data = f.read()
        print(data.min(), data.max())
        # output: 0 19596
```

Comment: Are you comparing pixel values with rasterio and qgis?

Comment: Both. In the above example, I use rasterio to compare the pixel ranges (note the difference). In QGIS, I can see a difference in the range of the "before" and "after" images, too. However, the absolute values are different from those reported by rasterio for some reason.

Comment: can you share the image with the values in rasterio and qgis?

Comment: Can you post that here?

Comment: Lossy compression will change the pixel values.  [See this note](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/jp2openjpeg.html#lossless-compression)

Comment: JPEG2000 *can* be lossless but you did not show that you use appropriate parameters to make sure it is. By default it *will* change pixel values if the algorithm feels like it.

Answer (score 0):

My humble guess as I don't have the input file to try is that you are relying on some default parameter when writing the `ou.jp2` file.

could you try to copy all the metadata when writing the file instead:

```py
with rasterio.open('/tmp/in.jp2') as infile:

    kwargs = infile.profile.copy()

    with rasterio.open('/tmp/out.jp2', 'w', **kwargs) as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
```